# mysql_select_db("db_name") doesn`t work with freshly created DB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

**My PHP code**

```
$handle = mysql_connect();
echo ($handle) ? "Connected to mysql" : "Could not connect";

$db = mysql_select_db("users");
if ($db ==false) { 
    die(' Could Not select database so Exiting;');
} else {
    echo " Database selected;";
}
mysql_close($handle);
```

*This code works with default mysql databases like "test" or "mysql".*

**My Data Base creation code sequence:**

```
mariadb[none]> create database users;
mariadb[none]> use users;
mariadb[users]> create table registered_users ( user_name varchar(18), user_pass varchar(18) );
```

Comment: `mysql_` functions with MariaDB? Why `mysql_` functions in general?

Comment: As always, `echo mysql_error();`.  Does the connected DB user have `GRANT`s on the new database?

Comment: dont create a database named as users because there may be a system database. i think you should change your database name

Comment: default opensuse pack affords mariadb. And I am new to databases.

Comment: New code should not be written with `mysql_*()` at this point, as it has been deprecated in PHP 5.5.  Start learning either MySQLi or PDO.I recommend reading http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's basically happening is you are connected to test by default please supply parameters mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") ;

Should work with no doubt.

Comment: "should" and "no doubt"? :D see comments on similar answers here

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli_` functions instead:

```
$localhost=''; //SQL Host
$dbuser=''; //Database Username 
$dbpass=''; //Database Password
$dbname=''; //Database Name

$connect=mysqli_connect($localhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
```

`mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Can you expand on why you are suggesting this?

Comment: I should have explained, the reason I commented is to encourage you to expand on your answer by giving more explanation. Generally speaking, StackOverflow answers should include code and explanations of that code.

Comment: I Added A Example, That's What You Mean Right ?

Comment: That helps, yes. I guess the other part of this is why `mysqli_connect` versus `mysql_connect`? (For the original poster's benefit as well as anyone else reading this.)

Comment: @jakerella I updated my answer, my English is way better now xD _man how stupid I was "and probably still"_